# Date format in EventLogQuery?

Tags: .net, c#-4.0

I want to build query string to query Event log with in a date range. I am doing it as below. But facing invalid query error, "Specified query is invalid". I compared my query with the filter provided in Eventlog viewer XML view.

*[System[Provider[@Name='.NET Runtime' or @Name='Application Error' or @Name='Application Hang'] and TimeCreated[@SystemTime>='2013-08-13T17:29:56.000Z' and @SystemTime<='2013-08-14T17:29:56.999Z']]]

```
string queryString = "*[System[Provider[@Name='Application Error' or @Name='Application Hang' or @Name='ThomsonONE' or @Name='DFContainer'] and TimeCreated[@SystemTime&gt;='" + "2013-08-13T04:00:00.000Z" + "' and @SystemTime&lt;='" + "2013-08-14T03:59:59.999Z" + "']]]";      

    EventLogQuery eventsQuery = new EventLogQuery(fileNames[0], PathType.FilePath, queryString);
    EventLogReader logReader = new EventLogReader(eventsQuery);
                               for (EventRecord eventInstance = logReader.ReadEvent();
                               null != eventInstance; eventInstance = logReader.ReadEvent())

        {
        }
```

Please let me know whats wrong in this above code?

Comment: I got it, the above code is correct, I just need to remove &gt; and &lt; so its resolved.